# Why storage access functions not working on android 10 API-29 ? error=13, Permission denied?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

> This example code is to create video from images and music.
> Code running on till API level 28 but when I just upgrade to
> Build version 29 then it starts crashing. I tried the most solution
> but could not find the proper reason and solution.
> Please let me know...

2

```
021-01-08 19:48:16.045 18413-19578/com.example.photovideomaker E/audio: io
    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/user/0/com.example.photovideomaker/files/ffmpeg": error=13, Permission denied
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1050)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:698)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:563)
        at com.example.photovideomaker.service.CreateVideoService.joinAudio(CreateVideoService.java:252)
        at com.example.photovideomaker.service.CreateVideoService.createVideo(CreateVideoService.java:89)
        at com.example.photovideomaker.service.CreateVideoService.onHandleIntent(CreateVideoService.java:83)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:78)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:133)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:141)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:698) 
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:563) 
        at com.example.photovideomaker.service.CreateVideoService.joinAudio(CreateVideoService.java:252) 
        at com.example.photovideomaker.service.CreateVideoService.createVideo(CreateVideoService.java:89) 
        at com.example.photovideomaker.service.CreateVideoService.onHandleIntent(CreateVideoService.java:83) 
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:78) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

> This function throwing the error "On Process.runtime"

```
private void createVideo() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        toatalSecond = (application.getSecond() * ((float) application.getSelectedImages().size())) - DEFAULT_FONT_SCALE;
        joinAudio();
        while (true) {
            if (ImageCreatorService.isImageComplate) {
                Log.e("image creation ", " complte");

                break;
            }else {
                Log.e("image creation ", "not complte");
            }
        }
        Log.e("createVideo", "video create start");
        new File(FileUtils.TEMP_DIRECTORY, "video.txt").delete();
        for (int i = 0; i < application.videoImages.size(); i++) {
            appendVideoLog(String.format("file '%s'", application.videoImages.get(i)));
        }

        File r0=new File(FileUtils.TEMP_DIRECTORY, "video.txt");
        String videoPath = new File(FileUtils.APP_DIRECTORY, getVideoName()).getAbsolutePath();
        String[] inputCode = application.getMusicData() != null ? new String[]{
                FileUtils.getFFmpeg(this), "-r",
                String.valueOf(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE / application.getSecond()),
                "-f", "concat", "-safe", "0", "-i", r0.getAbsolutePath(), "-i",
                audioFile.getAbsolutePath(), "-strict", "experimental", "-r", "30",
                "-t", String.valueOf(toatalSecond), "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset",
                "ultrafast", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-ac", "2", videoPath}
        : new String[]{FileUtils.getFFmpeg(this),
                "-r", String.valueOf(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE / application.getSecond()),
                "-f", "concat", "-i", r0.getAbsolutePath(), "-r", "30", "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", videoPath};

        System.gc();
        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(inputCode);
            while (!Util.isProcessCompleted(process)) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
                while (true) {
                    String line = reader.readLine();
                    if (line != null) {
                        Log.e("process", line);
                        appendLog(line);
                        final int incr = durationToprogtess(line);
                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                if (receiver != null) {
                                    receiver.onVideoProgressUpdate(incr);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        mBuilder.setProgress(100, ((int) ((75.0f * ((float) incr)) / 100.0f)) + 25, false);
                        mNotifyManager.notify(1001, mBuilder.build());
                    }else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Util.destroyProcess(process);
        }
        mBuilder.setContentText("Video created :" + FileUtils.getDuration(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)).setProgress(0, 0, false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(1001, mBuilder.build());
        try {
            long fileSize = new File(videoPath).length();
            String artist = getResources().getString(R.string.artist_name);
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("_data", videoPath);
            values.put("_size", Long.valueOf(fileSize));
            values.put("mime_type", "video/mp4");
            values.put("artist", artist);
            values.put("duration", Float.valueOf(toatalSecond * 1000.0f));
            getContentResolver().insert(Media.getContentUriForPath(videoPath), values);
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            sendBroadcast(new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE", Uri.fromFile(new File(videoPath))));
        } catch (Exception e3) {
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }

        buildNotification(videoPath);
        final String str = videoPath;
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (receiver != null) {
                    receiver.onVideoProgressUpdate(100);
                    receiver.onProgressFinish(str);
                }
            }
        });
        FileUtils.deleteTempDir();
       stopSelf();
    }
```

I have tried checking the directory in storage and check mkdir is working or not but this function purely works for creating video from a collection of images, themes, and audio. as per android

Comment: `This function throwing the error` Can be. But that is s lot of code. Please tell the statement that causes the error.

Comment: Error trace Indicate on this line `process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(inputCode);`

Comment: And what is the value of `inputCode'?

Comment: Audio, Video paths

Comment: Please be serious. Tell full path, exact value.

Comment: application.getMusicData() :-  Get file absolute path and conver to MusicData() object ,   FileUtils.getFFmpeg(this) :- It will give FFMPEG file Lib file , String.valueOf(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE / application.getSecond()) :- Return total sec to be generate video size duration,  r0.getAbsolutePath() :- Path list of all generated images for creating video,  audioFile.getAbsolutePath() :- Audio File path require for join with video,  String.valueOf(toatalSecond): Total sec of video, videoPath :- Output path for new generated video through this commang